# Multiple cards opening in RecyclerView when clicked on only Single card

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a periodic table app.
`RecyclerView` was used to display items in listed fashion.
When an item is clicked then the hidden layout which contains element details changes from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`.

[image: 1st Item clicked]

Problem is that when I click 1st item and then scroll then every 11th item is opened (11,21,31..) and when closed every 11th item is closed.

Code for hiding and unhiding the details layout:

```
    holder.element_single_card.setOnClickListener {

        if(holder.hidden_elements.visibility == View.GONE) {
            holder.hidden_elements.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        else{
            holder.hidden_elements.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

Code of Parent Layout containing all text views for showing details of element

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/element_hidden_information"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_shown_information"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_symbol"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_period"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_symbol"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_mass"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_period"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_density"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_mass"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_boiling_point"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_density"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_melting_point"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_boiling_point"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_electron_affinity"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_melting_point"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/element_summary"
                android:layout_below="@id/element_electron_affinity"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: 11th Item automatically opened]

How can I stop every 11th item from opening and what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should have a `Boolean` type *isExpanded* variable in your model along with getter/setter methods.
This variable will be responsible for storing the expanded state corresponding to each item.

From onClick call -

```
 myModel.setIsExpanded(true);
```

and write below code in `onBindViewHolder()`

```
if(myModel.getIsExpanded())
{
    holder.hidden_elements.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
else
{
    holder.hidden_elements.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Since `RecyclerView` reuses it's `viewHolder` objects, you can't rely on the earlier state of the `View`.

Let me know if you need any more clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you scroll down the 11th element is reusing the same view as the 1st element(this is a desired android feature due to memory constraints) you need to reset the layout to `View.GONE` if the element you are trying to display is not in open state.

To do this you cannot rely on the view's current state as you are doing in `OnClickListener` and should instead maintain a state of selected or clicked in the list item itself that you are using to display the data.

Further documentation about view recycling can be found in the [official](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) Android docs.